# Accessing the Trade History via Cryptopia API using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm trying to access to the sum of the last buy and sell orders for all the coins on Cryptopia using the official API. 
First of all here is the link to the API: https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Forum/Thread/255

When I make a request for a single coin, everything works just fine.

```
  $coin = 100;
  $url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarketHistory/". $coin . "/" . 1;
  $curl_dscr = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3');
  curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl_dscr), 1);

  if (empty($data['Data'])) exit;
  $sell_total = 0;
  $buy_total = 0;
  foreach ($data['Data'] as $pair) {
    list($market) = explode('_', $pair['Label']);
    if ($pair['Type'] == 'Sell')
      $sell_total += $pair['Total'];
    elseif ($pair['Type'] == 'Buy') {
      $buy_total += $pair['Total'];
    }
  }
  echo $sell_total;
  echo $buy_total;
  echo $url;
```

However, when I create an array of coins and run the script on Terminal, the script outputs nothing.  I don't even get an error. Here is the code.

```
  $coins = array(1261,5313);
  foreach ($coins as $coin) {
      $url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarketHistory/" . $coin . "/" . 1;
      $curl_dscr = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3');
      curl_setopt($curl_dscr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
      $data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl_dscr), 1);

      if (empty($data['Data'])) exit;
      $sell_total = 0;
      $buy_total = 0;
      foreach ($data['Data'] as $pair) {
          list($market) = explode('_', $pair['Label']);
          if ($pair['Type'] == 'Sell')
              $sell_total += $pair['Total'];
          elseif ($pair['Type'] == 'Buy') {
              $buy_total += $pair['Total'];
          }
      }
      echo $sell_total;
      echo $buy_total;
      echo $url;
      unset($coin);
  }
```

Comment: have you tried adding any debug information at all? such as, the raw response value of `curl_exec($curl_dscr)` before it is json_decoded, or the raw value of `$data`? Are you invoking the script directly or calling it from an interactive shell like `psysh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain how you are testing your code, i just run it and it worked, it display:

```
0.000635710.00052873https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarketHistory/1261/1
```

Comment: Oh, it worked out just fine now. Probably it was an error caused by the API. They were having a maintenance time to time.  However, I only get the results for the first coin in the array. The URL doesn't get updated in the foreach loop for the second coin in the array.

Comment: Actually, I figured out that one too. Thanks!